# Cannot read properties of undefined - Error on function call

Tags: javascript, function

I am receiving an error when calling the `getComputerChoice()` function that contains the following code:

```js
var options = ["rock" , "paper" , "scissor"];

function getComputerChoice(options) {
    let choice = options[Math.floor(Math.random()*options.length)];
    console.log(choice);
}

getComputerChoice();

`your text`
// I'm Getting an error while calling this function 

// Full error - index.js:7 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'length')
    at getComputerChoice
```

The error message states that there is a `TypeError` and that I am unable to read the properties of undefined, specifically the length of the `options` array.

Comment: your function expect parameter `options` which you are not providing while calling it. `function getComputerChoice(options)`. Either remove parameter because you have declared it globally on top.

Answer (score 1):

In your code, the `options` used by the function `getComputerChoice` is the parameter passed to it. You aren't passing anything to your function and so the value being used for `options` inside the function is `undefined` thus causing your error.

Simply change the function call as follows:

```
getComputerChoice(options);
```